# Python threads stuck at _ssl.sslwrap

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, python-requests

I have a multithreaded Python (2.7.6) application that sometimes get stuck when calling `requests.post` (the library is at version 2.5.1). Here's what I get for the stack trace (found by calling `sys._current_frames()`):

```
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 99 in post
  return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 49 in request
  response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 461 in request
  resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 573 in send
  r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 370 in send
  timeout=timeout
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 518 in urlopen
  body=body, headers=headers)
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 322 in _make_request
  self._validate_conn(conn)
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727 in _validate_conn
  conn.connect()
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238 in connect
  ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 254 in ssl_wrap_socket
  return context.wrap_socket(sock)
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 80 in wrap_socket
  return wrap_socket(socket, ciphers=self.ciphers, **kwargs)
"/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 487 in wrap_socket
  ciphers=ciphers)
"/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 241 in __init__
  ciphers)
```

Checking line 241 of ssl.py, I find it's the last line of this call:

```
self._sslobj = _ssl.sslwrap(self._sock, server_side,
                            keyfile, certfile,
                            cert_reqs, ssl_version, ca_certs,
                            ciphers)
```

When threads get stuck here, it appears that they are stuck permanently. I was able to see 24 threads stuck here for about two days before I had to restart my application. I'm using `requests` quite a bit and the vast majority of the time there is no problem, but for some reason the 24 threads all got stuck within the space of a couple minutes. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Note: I can't consistently reproduce it other than just letting it run and waiting for a batch of threads to eventually get stuck.

Comment: My best guess is that you're on a WiFi or otherwise swaying connection and that these threads are simply waiting for a handshake request to come in but none is ever received. You could set a timeout and kill off the threads to ensure resourced isn't getting wasted.

Comment: @Torxed not WiFi. It's actually running in AWS.

Comment: It's possible that library cannot run in a threadsafe manner. You should consider using a library designed for asynchronous web tasks, like Twisted or aiohttp.

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/ says it is thread-safe